# MySQL Schema Design: One Possible Values Between Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, trigger, schema, ddl, check-constraints

I'm working on a schema for a MySQL database. I have tables which are derivatives of one another. For example, rather than a single "animals" table, I might have separate "mammals" and "birds" tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `mammals` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `species_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `fur_color` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `birds` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `species_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `wingspan` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

The tables are separate because a large percentage of the combined columns between the two tables are unique to one specific derivative (e.g. `fur_color` and `wingspan` in the example above). The different derivatives also have very different relationships to other tables.

However in some other tables we might want to reference a specific instance of one of those entities:

```
CREATE TABLE `pets` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `mammal_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `bird_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL
);
```

The above example would allow us to specify what species of animal each pet is, but there's a problem: the `pets` schema allows for values to be entered in both the `mammal_id` and `bird_id` column while in reality I only want to allow input in one or the other.

What is the best solution to this issue? I was considering a check constraint but according to the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Should I simply replicate the constraint as a trigger that throws an error, or is there a better solution that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

```
id, species_name, dominant_color, owner_id,  
type ENUM('mammal', 'bird', 'reptile', 'arachnid', ...),  
other_characteristics TEXT
```

Where `other_characteristics` has `JSON` in it.  You can add whatever you want there.

Other tips:  Do not blindly use (255); use some reasonable limit.  Once `wingspan` is in the `JSON`, you can get rid of the ridiculously precise `DECIMAL(11,8)`.